# Mongo: querying for object inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've tried using `$in` and `$elemMatch` to query for all objects matching `member_id` field within an object array, neither are returning data. Example queries:

```
db.events.find({"source_site":{"event_hosts":{$in:[{"member_id":12300113}]}}})
```

and

```
db.events.find({source_site:{event_hosts:{$elemMatch:{member_id:12300113}}}})
```

Sample data to query in Mongo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("541890c2660a17aa1f7b7bd4"),
    "source_site" : {
        "event_hosts" : [
            {
                "member_id" : 12300113,
                "member_name" : "Sal Corthen"
            },
            {
                "member_id" : 139930702,
                "member_name" : "Erin Morgen"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match a `member_id` directly, you can use:

```js
db.events.find({"source_site.event_hosts.member_id":12300113})
```

or using `$in`:

```js
db.events.find({"source_site.event_hosts.member_id":{$in:[12300113]}})
```

or using `$elemMatch`:

```js
db.events.find({"source_site.event_hosts":{$elemMatch:{"member_id":12300113}}})
```